# ImportError: No module named requests using two versions of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-3.4

I've python 3.4.1 installed, and need to run python 2 script. I've installed python 2.7.5 by running `make install`. When i run my script it writes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/roseltorg/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Then I'm trying to install requests module but:

```
pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests-2.11.1-py3.4.egg
Cleaning up...
```

How to force install this module for python 2.7?

Comment: There is a thing for this kind of problems called virtualenv.

Comment: Do you have a file named `requests.py` or a directory named `requests`?

Comment: `/path/to/your/custom/python -m pip install requests`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using virtualenv in such scenario.

```
virtualenv -p path_to_python2.7 .(current dir)
source bin/activate
pip install requests
```

Comment: That's good advice for other reasons, but doesn't appear to offer a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: I think it will solve OP's problem if he has to run python 2.7 script by installing python 2.7, Best way to create virtualenv for 2.7 and run into it.

Answer (score 1):

It is installing to python 3.4 with `pip` which means `pip` pointing to `pip3`. Try doing this

```
pip2 install requests
```